# Storing Token from API w/ Express http-proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, proxy

I'm setting up a universal React app and using [this project](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example) as a base. I am successfully proxying requests (using [http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy)) to my Laravel backend. However, I'm new to Nodejs and I don't know how the best method to securely store a JWT from the proxied server to the client.

My initial thought was to store the token to localStorage, but the problem is that the express server won't have access to it. So my next guess would be to store it as a cookie, but I'm not sure how to store it on the client or include it as a header for all outgoing requests (additionally, I would likely need some sort of csrf middleware).

So how would I manipulate the response from my api server to put a token in a cookie that is set in the client, then use that as a bearer token for all api requests?

```
// server.js
const targetUrl = 'http://' + config.apiHost + ':' + config.apiPort;
const app = new Express();
const server = new http.Server(app);

const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
  target: targetUrl,
  changeOrigin: true
});

// Proxy to Auth endpoint
app.use('/auth', (req, res) => {
  // on a successful login, i want to store the token as a cookie
  proxy.web(req, res, {target: targetUrl});
});

// Proxy to api endpoint
app.use('/api', (req, res) => {
  // use the token in the cookie, and add it as a authorization header in the response
  proxy.web(req, res, {target: targetUrl});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that the response from the auth endpoint in laravel is like this:

```
{ 
    "token" : "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ"
}
```

This code will do what you want:

```
// server.js
const targetUrl = 'http://' + config.apiHost + ':' + config.apiPort;
const Express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const app = new Express();
const server = new http.Server(app);
const Cookies = require( "cookies" )

const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
  target: targetUrl,
  changeOrigin: true
});

// Proxy to Auth endpoint
app.use('/auth', (req, res) => {
  // on a successful login, i want to store the token as a cookie
  // this is done in the proxyRes
  proxy.web(req, res, {target: targetUrl});
});

// Proxy to api endpoint
app.use('/api', (req, res) => {
  // use the token in the cookie, and add it as a authorization header in the response
  var cookies = new Cookies( req, res )
  req.headers.authorization = "JWT " + cookies.get('jwt-token');
  proxy.web(req, res, {target: targetUrl});
});

proxy.on('proxyRes', function(proxyRes, req, res) {
    if (req.originalUrl === '/auth') {
        var cookies = new Cookies( req, res )
        var body = '';
        var _write = res.write;
        var _end = res.end;
        var _writeHead = res.writeHead;
        var sendHeader = false;

        res.writeHead = function () {
            if (sendHeader) {
                _writeHead.apply( this, arguments );
            }
        }
        res.write = function (data) {
            body += data;
        }
        res.end = function () {
            sendHeader = true;
            var parsed = JSON.parse(body);
            cookies.set('jwt-token', parsed.token);
            _write.apply(this, [ body ]);
            _end.apply(this, arguments);
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Looks like the only issue I'm running into is that the var parsed = JSON.parse(body); throw an error: Unexpected token. The response from the server is json. I also attempted JSON.parse(body.toString('utf8')), but I still get the same error

Comment: Please post what `body` is. `console.log(body);` Probably  some extra characters, or illegal JSON which needs some preprocessing.

Comment: Actually, that was my fault. I needed to adjust the targetUrl (targetUrl: targetUrl + '/auth'). Now I'm getting a different error, but this may be on my part as well:

[1] _http_outgoing.js:429
[1]   if (this.finished) {
[1]           ^
[1]
[1] TypeError: Cannot read property 'finished' of undefined
[1]     at OutgoingMessage.write (_http_outgoing.js:429:11)
[1]     at ServerResponse.res.end (server_es6.js:60:14)
[1]     at IncomingMessage.onend (_stream_readable.js:490:10)
[1]     at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:260:16)
[1]     at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
...

Comment: What module is _http_outgoing.js part of? Is this your script?